# Активная кнопка после нажатия на чекбокс?

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать `<input class="btn"...` активным при установке флажка на checkbox, и наоборот? т.е удалить `disabled=""`

```
<input id="form" required="" type="checkbox">
<label for="form">
Отправляя сообщение, я подтверждаю, что ознакомлен и согласен с политикой конфиденциальности данного сайта
</label>

<input class="btn" value="Заказать" type="submit" disabled="">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно достать атрибут и назначать ему true или false
написал на js и на jquery

```js
//JavaScript
form.onchange = function(){
  var button = document.body.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];
  if(button.disabled) button.disabled = false;
  else button.disabled = true;
}

//Jquery
$('#form').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) $('.btn').attr('disabled', false);
  else $('.btn').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="form" required="" type="checkbox">
<label for="form">
Отправляя сообщение, я подтверждаю, что ознакомлен и согласен с политикой конфиденциальности данного сайта
</label>

<input class="btn" value="Заказать" type="submit" disabled="">
```

Comment: `$('.btn').attr('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'))`

Comment: Кстати, jQuery вроде не просили.

Comment: Да можно и jQuery, как надежнее?

Comment: @steep, при такой простой задаче и отсутствии IE8- совершенно без разницы.

Comment: Использовать 'onchange', тем более для формы, плохо.

Comment: @Qwertiy, там же на input висит?

Comment: @steep, никак, просто не знал чем вы пользуётесь)

Comment: @Horchynskyi, ой. не ожидал, что инпут называется form.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById('allow').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  document.getElementById('submit').disabled = !e.target.checked
})
```

```html
<form>
  <label><input type=checkbox id=allow> Разблокировать кнопку</label>
  <input type=submit id=submit value=Отправить disabled>
</form>
```